# Can't pass a instance of a class to WCF service

Tags: c#, wcf

This is the code I have written. But the add product method is not working. Can any one please help me?

```
public class Sales : ISales
    {
        ArrayList plist;

        public Sales()
        {
            plist = new ArrayList();
            plist.Add(new Product() { productId=1,name="com",description="fsf",price=2000});
        }


        public void addProduct(Product p)
        {
             plist.Add(new Product() { productId = 2, name = "com", description = "fsf", price = 2000 });

        }

    }
```

This is the interface class. get price method is working. But get product method is not working.
I can't understand what is the problem.

```
namespace WcfService2
{

[ServiceContract]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(Product))]
public interface ISales
{

    [OperationContract]
    double getprice(int id);

    [OperationContract]
    Product getProduct(int pid);

    [OperationContract]
    void addProduct(Product p);

}

//need to have datacontarct for composite data type
[DataContract]
public class Product
{
    [DataMember]
    public int productId { set; get; }
    [DataMember]
    public string name { set; get; }
    [DataMember]
    public string description { set; get; }
    [DataMember]
    public double price { set; get; }

}




}
```

Comment: You may need to define what you mean by “the add product method is not working” ...

Comment: so, what happens? I mean, at a first glance everything looks ok

Comment: Are you intending on storing the parameter `p` that is passed to `AddProduct`?  You're not doing that in your example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The implementation of `addProduct` method doesn't seem right. You have a parameter declared but you don't use it. If you want to add the product passed as the parameter to your list, you should use:

```
public void addProduct(Product p)
{
    plist.Add(p);
}
```